# Where does Android ICS store the cursor graphic?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb-on-the-go, mouse

If you plug in a mouse to an Android device, a cursor shows up. I was wondering where that cursor graphic is stored? I'm a root user and want to know in case I wanted to modify it in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mouse cursor graphics can be located in the `framework-res.apk`. Specifically, `res/drawable-x/pointer_arrow.png` inside the APK file where x (suffix of drawable) is pixel density class of your device.