Android 14 replaced the small mouse cursor with a big insectoud cursor, how to revert to small mouse cursor?
Android had a small cursor with the form of a mammal (mouse),
but Android 14 replaced this with a bigger, insectoid cursor, and the settings just has an option to make it even larger (which is the opposite of how to fix this.)
Must flash (Pixel 6: how to flash Sailfish/Ubuntu without a desktop (just unlocked bootloader + On-the-Go flash)?) to do this, or can do this without flash?

Related: Where does Android (ICS) store the cursor graphic?

@Andrew Cool. Must have root to use this, or can fix cursor without root?

Unfortunately, modifying system resource almost certainly requires root, or even custom ROM.

Most operating systems do not require root to use custom cursors. This is not a request for a custom cursor, but just to go back to the old small mouse cursor which the old version of Android has.

If what you want doesn't exist / isn't available in the version you're running, that it was available before in an older version or whether or not it's 'custom' is a moot point. The fact remains that modifying system resource almost certainly requires root, or even custom ROM.

Exists: [quote=https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63921/where-does-android-ics-store-the-cursor-graphic/63927#63927 ] Mouse cursor graphics can be located in the framework-res.apk. Specifically, res/drawable-x/pointer_arrow.png inside the APK file where x (suffix of drawable) is pixel density class of your device.[/quote]
All other operating systems require superuser to replace the launcher (Launchpad on OSX, explorer.exe on Windows, gnome on Linux), but Android does not require superuser for this. Is much less drastic to switch to an old/new mouse cursor.

Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636855/custom-mouse-pointer-on-android/55482761#55482761 limited to just a single application, or can use to switch system to old/new mouse cursor?
[All other operating systems have user-accessible menus to switch to old/new mouse cursors, don't know of a reason Android would not do this too.]
