Pixel 6: how to flash Sailfish/Ubuntu without a desktop (just unlocked bootloader + On-the-Go flash)?
Ubuntu Touch (alternative to Sailfish): https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/
Sailfish: https://docs.sailfishos.org/Reference/Android_Compatibility/#hardware-support
Definition/instructions of flash: https://phone.docs.ubuntu.com/en/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices;
Must switch to Sailfish or Ubuntu to have the normal cursor? Do not wish to purchase a desktop just to flash (can not afford a room; would not have purpose for a smartphone if could afford a desktop + a room.)
Most compute devices allow to install (flash) new operating systems from flash (Universal Serial Bus) storage; how to do this on phones?
Does this require an "On-the-Go" Universal Serial Bus device which includes a small Linux (to execute ADB/fastboot)?
Do such On-The-Go devices exist, so do not have to purchase a whole laptop just to flash phone? Assistant suggests that such exist: https://poe.com/s/bthVjSoU5cwoE7azr2rg (just purchase such On-the-Go device which has the Sailfish/Ubuntu flash imagee, reboot your phone to the bootloader menu, use menu to load Ubuntu from flash)... can do this?

Related, there could be other apps on Play Store as well (example, but I guess your device needs to be rooted.

Found https://www.droidviews.com/create-bootable-usb-android/ (no root) but not sure you can use this to produce device which is sideloadable or does fastboot

No, obviously not.

You don't need a laptop. A cheap micro system like raspberry pi (1 to 5) is sufficient for sending adb or fastboot commands via USB to an Android phone. Raspberry is a real USB host so no USB OTG mode is needed.

Raspberry is a desktop; it requires an outlet with alternating current, plus a monitor, just as other desktops do; It is not possible unless you can afford a room.

If you wish to install a different OS you will need a PC on mains power as interruption of the flashing process can cause the phone to be bricked and all custom ROM tools, i.e. fastboot run on PC/Desktop. Unclear if you know about this already, if you want to use a Linux like environment on your phone, take a look at Termux, see https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Software for some possible uses.

Wish Android shipped with bash/ash (as all other Linux distributions do), but since it does not, Termux is cool. But doubt can use Termux to fix system issues (such as https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/258059/android-14-replaced-the-small-mouse-cursor-with-a-big-insectoud-cursor-how-to-r?noredirect=1#comment350811_258059) unless you flash root

Does an On-the-Go module exist which can execute fastboot (to flash a new operating system or flash root)? [The phone must have battery full, + the module must have minimalist Linux distribution to do fastboot.]
Which flash modules can just do as storage, if you reboot phone to bootloader to sideload new operating system/root (Assistant -- https://poe.com/s/bthVjSoU5cwoE7azr2rg  -- suggests On-the-Go modules can do this)?

Can use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixapplications.iso2usb to produce sideloadable flash to do this? Descriptions says no root to use
